# Postgres - jsonb : Update key in column with value taken from another table

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.5

I am using postgres 9.5. I have a profile table, which lists the names:

```
public.profiles:
      id |   first_name      |        last_name
      --- ---------------  ---------------------
       1        Jason                   Bourne
       2       Jhonny                    Quest
```

I have an invoices table:

```
  public.invoices:
            invoice_id      |         billing_address       |    profile_id
         ------------------   -----------------------------  ---------------------
                   1          {                                        2
                               "address_line1": "445 Mount 
                                     Eden Road", 
                               "city":"Mount Eden", 
                               "country": "Auckland"
                              }
```

I want to update the billing_address column of the invoices table with the first_name and last_name from the profile table, like :

```
 public.invoices:
                invoice_id      |         billing_address       |    profile_id
             ------------------   -----------------------------  ---------------------
                       1          {
                                   "name" : "Jhonny Quest"                2
                                   "address_line1": "445 Mount 
                                         Eden Road", 
                                   "city":"Mount Eden", 
                                   "country": "Auckland"
                                  }
```

To do so, I have tried using jsonb_set:

```
UPDATE invoices AS i SET billing_address = jsonb_set(billing_address,'{name}', SELECT t::jsonb FROM (SELECT CONCAT (p.first_name,p.middle_name, p.last_name) FROM profiles p WHERE p.id = i.profile_id)t )
```

It throws an error at SELECT. TBH I am not even sure if any of that statement is legal. Looking for any guidance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Click: demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=058387ac28db60f0d4038e85341eb521)

```
UPDATE invoices i
SET billing_address = s.new_billing_address
FROM (
    SELECT
        i.invoice_id,
        jsonb_set(
            billing_address, 
            '{name}'::text[], 
            to_jsonb(concat_ws(' ', first_name, last_name))
        ) AS new_billing_address
    FROM 
        invoices i
    JOIN profiles p ON i.profile_id = p.id
) s
WHERE s.invoice_id = i.invoice_id;
```

Creating the `SELECT` with joining the second table; Afterwards you are able to create the new JSON object out of the name parts using `to_jsonb()` and the concat operator `||` (or concat_ws(), of course, as mentioned in the comments).

Comment: This is a good answer, but jsonb_insert isn't available in 9.5.  Also, I would suggest using concat_ws(' ', first_name, middle_name, last_name) to avoid nulling out the entire field if one of the fields is null.

Comment: @Jeremy Thanks for the advice, didn't see the 9.5 requirement. Changed to jsonb_set(). The concat_ws() advice is nice to have. Took it as well :)